# PHP script does not upload values from HTML form to SQL database

Tags: php, sql, forms, post

I face some issues uploading data from an HTML form to my database. I separated the actual upload and the input in two different files.

Here is the input HTML input form and the command to include the upload.php file:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();
?>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) { //shop upload
        require 'upload.php';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?></title>
  <?php include 'css/cssuser.html'; ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">      
      <form action="user.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Country<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='country' />
            </div>

            //....

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Price range<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name='price_range' />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="upload">Upload</button> 
      </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This input should be processed by the following php upload script

```
<?php
require 'geocoding.php';
/* 
Upload shop details to database and check if shop already exists
 */

// Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
$country = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['country']);
$city = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['city']);
$address = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['address']);
$shop_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['shop_name']);
$description = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['description']);
$opening_hours = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['opening_hours']);
$price_range = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['price_range']);

//forward geocode the adress to a longitude and latitude value 
use reverseGeocoding\Geocoding; 
$geo = new Geocoding("my API Key which works fine");
$coordinates = $geo ->getCoordinates("Friedrich-Missler-Strasse 43");

$lat = $location->lat
$lon = $location->lng

//Get user id and select it from database 
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$id = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'id' FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

// Check if user with that email already exists
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shops WHERE address='$address' AND shopname='$shop_name'") or die($mysqli->error());

// We know shop exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'This shop already exists';
    header("location: error.php");
}
else { // Shop does not exist in a database, proceed...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO shops (country, city, address, lon, lat, shopname, description, opening, price_range, id) " 
            . "VALUES ('$country','$city','$address','$lon','$lat','$shop_name','$description','$opening_hours','$price_range','$id')";

    // Add shop to the database
    if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

        $_SESSION['message'] =

                 "$shop_name has been added to the database";

        header("location: user.php")

    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Upload failed';
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}

?>
```

The problem is that every time I fill out the form and post it to the server the data is not stored in the database. The website redirects me to the blank users.php page (page of the form). It is quite unlikely that the cause is due to a malfunctioning database since the registration works perfectly fine. 
This is an excerpt from the corresponding database 
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated since I am a beginner in the field of PHP

---

In case anyone wonders where

```
$lat = $location->lat
$lon = $location->lng
```

comes from:

```
    public function getCoordinates($address)
    {
        $data = [
            'address' => $address,
            'key' => $this->api_key
        ];
        $addressData = $this->request($this->callurl, $data);
        $location = json_decode($addressData)->results[0]->geometry->location;
        return [ 'latitude' => $location->lat, 'longitude' => $location->lng];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me known if the information given is not sufficient. So I can improve both future questions and answers

Comment: Is your form's action, `user.php`, the right one? I.e. the one you name "php upload script" in your post?

Comment: the form which executes the upload is called "upload.php". Is this the one I need to insert into the "action" part of the form?

Comment: Do not use `escape_string` in new projects. The proper way of passing data to SQL is prepared statements. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never put PHP variables in SQL queries.

Comment: @Jakob: Well, if you want the browser to post to it, then yes.

Comment: @stickybit thanks for the hint. However, this only leaves me with a blank page and no data entry in the database

Comment: You have some syntax errors in PHP. I suggest to use a proper IDE with syntax highlighting and linting. Also try: https://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: @Dharman thanks. I will have a look at php storm